# The lowest dpi drawable is being used on a xxhdpi screen

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have two imagebuttons, with dimensions 256x256 dp and `scaleType="centerCrop"`.
When I see the preview in AS or when I launch the application on my nexus 5 the images are blurry. The images are of the right dimensions for the respective folders, up to xxxhdpi(192x192).

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_width="256dp"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@mipmap/button_off"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="256dp"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:id="@+id/second_button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@mipmap/second_off"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it right - in your XML layout file you set an `ImageButton` with `width=256dp` and `height=256dp`, and src=drawable/your_drawable. The `xxxhdpi` drawable has width and height `192px` (I assume than mdpi - 48, hdpi - 72, xhdpi - 96, xxhdpi - 144, xxxhdpi - 192).

If so, than of course the images are blurred, because you set the `ImageButtons` width/height `in mdpi` (in xml to 256dp), but you used `144x144` (nexus 5 is xxhdpi) Drawable stretched (because of the scaleType=`centerCrop`).

If you don't want to have stretched images, here are some options for you (maybe not all):

1. you need to change the scaleType to centerInside (or without scaleType) - you will get smaller buttons - the images are scaleDowned only if needed
2. you need to make the ImageButton smaller - 48x48
3. you need to add bigger drawable resources - your mdpi drawable should be as big as your ImageButton in xml (mdpi - 256x 256, hdpi - 384x384, xhdpi - 512x512, xxhdpi - 768x768, xxxhdpi - 1024x1024)
4. you post some layout code (XML) in your question with detailed drawable resources resolution which you used and maybe we can make further investigation in your problem

Comment: if I use centerInside the images are tiny inside the imageButton. Definitely not the look I want. Making smaller imagebuttons is not viable since they are the main elements of the view. Also I don't believe it is the best option to provide an upscaled mdpi since smaller screens might get messed up. What do you want to know about the xml? Anyway look I edited my question.

Comment: Oh now i see one other problem - you use the mipmap folder and not the drawable folder  (mipmap is for the launcher icon, drawable for the app drawables) - as i mentioned above - if you want to use 256dp width/height ImageButton, you need to have the mdpi drawable 256x 256, hdpi - 384x384, xhdpi - 512x512 ...

Comment: I think I know that It makes no difference in which folder the images are, and actually in drawables-* there should be put only black/white icons. Anyway I fixed starting from your idea, I provided the same pictures in 1024x1024 in the mipmap-nodpi folder and used centerCrop. This scales the pictures back to 256x256 or whatever I chose the imageButton to be. Only downside is that on devices with screens less than 4" the lower button gets cropped and I can't get scrollView to work. Anyway thanks I am decently satisfied with this workaround.

Comment: You don't understand what I am saying. If you want to have 256dpx256dp ImageButton in layout XML than that width and height is equivalent to you mdpi drawables width/height and thats why your image is blurred. If you put it into nodpi folder, you will use the same 1024x1024 picture in every screen sizes, that's why in small devices it will be cropped.

Comment: I understand it and that fixed the blurring, so now I have to adapt the menu to smaller screen devices so that on those the image buttons and consequently the images are smaller without blurring

Answer (score 0):

Please see this documentation first

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

then check your project structure. It's quite unlikely you got this part wrong and there're low-res resources matching first.

Comment: The images are in the right directory with the right resolution, I checked all of them. The original images I did with photoshop were 1024x1024 and properly downscaled.